# Ask reason on "ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"?

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I know this restriction and alternative to rewrite SQL. But I wonder the reason why? Can anyone provide a inference on this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query like

```
select * from table where id in (select id from othertable)
```

will basically be interpreted as

```
select * from table where exists 
   (select id from othertable where table.id = othertable.id)
```

That is what you expect for that query. You especially expect the `IN` query to use the index on `othertable.id`. In the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-subqueries.html), it is described as

> Some optimizations that MySQL itself makes are: [...]
>
> - MySQL rewrites IN, ALL, ANY, and SOME subqueries in an attempt to take advantage of the possibility that the select-list columns in the subquery are indexed.

These are, not by pure coincidence, exactly the four operators mentioned in the error message if you add a `limit`:

```
select * from table where id in 
   (select id from othertable order by id limit 10)
```

> ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'.

Rewriting that query in a similar way is not directly possible anymore, as it is something different than

```
select * from table where exists 
   (select id from othertable where table.id = othertable.id 
    order by id limit 10)
```

To execute the `IN` with a limit, MySQL could retrieve the 10 first rows of `othertable`, store that resultset as a *derived subtable* and check if the id is in there. And you can of course do exactly that:

```
select * from table where id in 
   (select id from 
      (select id from othertable order by id limit 10) subtable)
```

This will, in analogy to the first example, be interpreted as

```
select * from table where exists 
   (select * from 
      (select id from othertable order by id limit 10) subtable
    where table.id = subtable.id)
```

So it is a mixture of how the optimizer works (it will rewrite the query), how `limit` works (it stops execution after *finding* rows, not skipping them), what is expected (the use of indexes) and ultimately if the developers decided to allow a specific syntax or not.

You could argue that MySQL could always fall back to execute the query as a derived table if it encounters `IN` with a `limit` subquery - but so could you by explicitely using a derived subtable. You could also argue that you can think of ways to implement that or implement that differently - and you are right, there are. That's why there is a "*yet*" in the error message. So feel free to implement them or at least describe them e.g. in a feature request as thoroughly as possible and under consideration of how all the other parts of MySQL work. But make sure they are actually faster than just using a subtable.